# CSS box-shadow weirdness in Firefox

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I have a weird issue when using box-shadow to apply a padding to the left and right side of a span which has its contents wrapping inside a container:

```
box-shadow:9px 0px 0px red, -9px 0px 0px red;
```

It applies the left shadow only to the first line, and the right shadow only to the last line.

http://jsfiddle.net/3zeL5ux8/2/ is a testcase that works as expected in Chrome and various IE versions (see http://imgur.com/XhX1kco for a perfect rendering), why does Firefox mess it up?

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
-moz-box-shadow:9px 0px 0px red, -9px 0px 0px red;
```

let me know the output. Can't debug right now.

Cheers

Comment: moz-box-shadow is not supported any more.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use all different box shadow property for all broweser, try following code :-

```
-moz-box-shadow: 9px 0px 0px red, -9px 0px 0px red; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 9px 0px 0px red, -9px 0px 0px red; 
box-shadow: 9px 0px 0px red, -9px 0px 0px red;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a property called `box-decoration-break: clone;`. This brings Firefox up to speed with IE and Chrome...